# Actualizar Algunos campos desde controlador y otros desde formulario - Controlador laravel

Tags: laravel

Como digo en el titulo necesito actualizar algunos campos desde el formulario y otros en el controlador de forma automática conozco esta forma

```
$ejemplo = Usershow::find($id)->update(['campo1' => $variable1]);
```

Pero me gustaría saber si hay otra forma ya que la tabla tiene muchos campos y solo quiero modificar uno desde el controlador y al tener que especificar todos queda un código muy largo.
he probado esto pero me da el request vació

```
$dsa = Dsa::Create($request->all());
$request->ejemplo = 1;
```

alguna idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el método fill para actualizar campos de forma masiva, este método acepta un array de datos:

```
$ejemplo->fill($request->all());
```

Ten en cuenta que los nombres de los campos que envíes deben coincidir con los campos del modelo/tabla.